# Stored procedure execution error: Unsupported statement type 'REMOVE_FILES

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Tried executing the PROCEDURE AS CALLER/OWNER with REMOVE files from External Stage, but its not working. any suggestions please?

Please note that the Procedure is defined in ROLEA and executed from ROLEB, procedure has USAGE privileges in ROLEB.

Comment: If you would like help on Stack Overflow, please:
Show the code you tried.  
Show the error message. 
Post them in text format.

Comment: Please find below the error

Stored procedure execution error: Unsupported statement type 'REMOVE_FILES

Comment: As @easleyfixed stated, you need to update your question with the full code of your SP before anyone can help you